# Trigger work after alert

Tags: jquery

I call a trigger below and it works only when add alert message. I want to auto fill country/state value in form. State drop down default hide. It show values on change of country drop down.

```
jQuery('#my_form select.country').change(function(){
   alert('test');
   var obj = jQuery('#my_form select.state');
   obj.val('myvalue');
});
fieldObject.trigger('change');
```

Comment: Did you mean it doesn't work without the `alert` ?

Comment: alert is blocking so it delays every code execution after it until you press cancel or ok.

if you want to debug use console.log() instead

Comment: Change event automatically triggers when you change the selection ,why you want to trigger manually

Comment: Yes it only work if i add alert message. without alert value not selected into state drop down.

Answer (score 0):

On changing of `country` you can call `ajax` for filling `state` like,

```
jQuery('#my_form select.country').change(function(){
   alert('test');
   var obj = jQuery('#my_form select.state');
   obj.html('<option value="1">State1</option><option value="2">State2</option>')
      .show();// shows the hidden drop down state
   // above options can be filled through ajAX
});
```